# REST request mapping to raw uris

Tags: spring, rest, security, uri, servlet-filters

I'm trying to write and request filter, in which I want to REST request to raw url so that I could implement security at common place with common logic. Would like to know what is efficient way of doing it or rather how do the API gateway maps the incoming request appropriate end point.

Scenario :

a. Endpoint - https:\my.domain.com\v1\api\accounts{id}\details?page=

b. Runtime request - https:\my.domain.com\v1\api\accounts\12\details?page=1
endpoint 'a' can be called only "admin"

Now in my filter I want to check if "b" maps to "a" and then I check if caller is admin or not. Accordingly I can pass the request to further down in the pipeline.

Possible solutions I considered:

1. base resource and method level role mapping -
2. Regular expression to match - Not getting correct expression to match this.

So far we have tried some regular expression in servlet filter but that is not working for path params.

Comment: what have you done so far? have you written anything? if so please edit your question and add more info

Comment: Updated the question